# Diskmounting problems after using windows

Tags: dual-boot, mount, disk

On mine laptop is use dualboot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Sometimes i must use Windows cos Ubuntu does not support some of mine software (10% not), but when i boot over to Ubuntu i cant mount mine harddisk(s) anymore and Ubuntu gives a warning that Windows block access to the harddisk(s).
Sometimes when i use Disk cleanup from windows the problem is temperary solved.
Does anybody know which file(s) from Windows blocking Ubuntu to access mine Harddisks ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly close Windows, or the disk will be considered as "in use" and will not be mounted by Ubuntu.

Some things to remember:

- [Desactivate Fast Startup (Windows 8 feature)](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/)
- Always use "Close" or "Reboot" button in Windows before booting Ubuntu (no poweroff by pressing the power button for 3secs, or unplug/plug AC)